# B660 GAMING X AX DDR4 (rev. 1.0) issue with graphic cards (no POST)

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

I bought a Gigabyte B660 GAMING X AX DDR4 (rev. 1.0) mainboard with a 12100F CPU mainly to reuse a GTX1080 TI GPU, which I had used in an other computer previously. I also have an even older GPU without any additional external power supply for debugging purposes.

**Problem:** If I start a Gigabyte B660 GAMING X AX DDR4 with the components I cannot reach POST and EZ Debug LED VGA is constantly on. The fans of the GPU spin as do all other installed fans.

**Debug steps:**
I tried both GPU in other computer previously and afterwards. Both of them work. I tried rebuilding everything multiple times without any effect.

**Current assumption:**
From my google research I identified that I could require  "Compatibility Support Module (CSM)" to be turned on, which is turned of in default for this mainboard?

**Components**

- Gigabyte B660 GAMING X AX DDR4
- 12100F CPU
- GTX1080 TI GPU
- 2 x 16-GB-DDR4-3000 RAM (PC4-24000)

Comment: Whatever this is, CSM (Legacy, "BIOS" mode) do NOT and should NOT be enabled. All current OSes from any of the 3 main "families" support and **recommend** UEFI mode.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason to believe that the GPU is not supported by the mainboard? I never heard of unsupported GPU.

Comment: No, no reason to believe there's some incompatibility in a cursory specifications glance. But do update UEFI just in case. And, even before the update you should try reseting the firmware to the default settings prior to inserting the graphics card.